# Combining two arrays into a hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm trying to combine two arrays into a hash.

```
@sample_array = ["one", "Two", "Three"]
@timesheet_id_array = ["96", "97", "98"]
```

I want to output the results into a hash called @hash_array. Is there a simple way to combine the two in a code block so that if you call puts at the end it looks like this in the console

```
{"one" => "96", "Two" => "97", "Three" => "98"}
```

I think this could be done in one or two lines of code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@hash_array = {}
@sample_array.each_with_index do |value, index|
  @hash_array[value] = @timesheet_id_array[index]
end
```

Comment: @RubyDude1012: not that this is bad, but in a language where you have the abstractions `zip` and `Hash` in the core, definitely it's not the idiomatic way to do it.

Answer (score 41):

try this

```
keys = [1, 2, 3]
values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
Hash[keys.zip(values)]
```

thanks

Comment: +1, but it's a been a long time since you can write `Hash[keys.zip(values)]`

Comment: remove `flatten` or it won't work, Hash takes pairs. As a semantic nit-picking, I think it's important for collections to have plural names: keys and values.

Comment: @tokland - It does work with `flatten`, in both MRI 1.8.7 and 1.9.3.  You're right that it's not needed there (it used to be, once).

Comment: Hooray! I finally get to use zip! Ruby idioms for the win.

Answer (score 2):

Imho that looks best:

```
[:a,:b,:c].zip([1,2,3]).to_h

# {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dr. Nic suggests 2 options explained well at http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/10/03/zip-vs-transpose/

Comment: only that the flattening is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
@hash_array = {}
0.upto(@sample_array.length - 1) do |index|
  @hash_array[@sample_array[index]] = @timesheet_id_array[index]
end
puts @hash_array.inspect
```